# Management of remote computer

Tags: c#, wmi

I have a domain on the Windows 2008. Is it possible to know all members of  local administrators group on any computer in the domain, and also remove some users from this group, and to know if user account is enable/disable with the help of WMI in C#? I have done these opportunities with the help of using `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespaces. But some features of my app don't work on other computer. Although they work on my PC.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#. WMI. " and such. Those are just tags, and belong in the tags only.